# + Operator does not work due to conditional

Tags: c++

The + operator doesn't work when attempting to put the variable `acidWeight` into `answerString`. Is this a logic error or a data type error?

```
string byName() {
    string acidName;
    string answerString;
    float acidWeight;

    cout << "Give me the name of the acid and I'll give you the weight." << endl;
    getline(cin, acidName);

    cout << endl << endl;

    if (acidName == "valine") {

        acidWeight = 117.1469;

    }

    else {

        cout << "This doesn't appear to be valid." << endl;

    }

    answerString = "The weight of " + acidName + "is " + acidWeight + "per mole";

    return answerString;
}
```

Comment: Use a [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to build formatted string output.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What do you mean by "does not work due to conditional"?

Comment: There was a build error due to `acidWeight`'s datatype.

Comment: This is what [an MCVE looks like](http://ideone.com/9cXOxA).

Comment: Where did you hear that this should be okay code? Programming by guessing won't work mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a logic error or a data type error?

It's a data type error. `acidWeight` is of type `float`, and there's no overload for the [`operator+()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) taking a `float` parameter.

---

If you want to build text formatted strings like you do with e.g. `std::cout`, you can use `std::ostringstream`:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "The weight of " << acidName << "is " << acidWeight << "per mole";
answerString = oss.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction: I was labouring under the false notion that you cannot use a const char* as an operator+() operand with a string in some c++ standards. I have changed my answer accordingly.

acidWeight is a float which does not have an operator+() function to allow for concatenation with a string.

As such, I guess you could say you are causing a data type error because you are attempting to use a function which does not exist for the intended data type (const char *).

With modern C++, you should use stringstreams from `<sstream>` to dynamically compose strings.

e.g.

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "Hi" << " again" << someVariable << ".";
std::string myString = ss.str();
const char *anotherExample = myString.c_str();
```

Comment: This is actually wrong. The missing operator is for `std::string` and `float`

Comment: Thanks Juan. Is that to say that the const char* + string op is valid?

Comment: Great I will look into which c std this was introduced in and edit my answer

Comment: C++98, the very first one!

Answer (score 0):

You can also just change the float to string since you aren't returning the float value. You just want to print it out.

```
string byName() {
    string acidName;
    string answerString;
    string acidWeight; //changed from float to string

    cout << "Give me the name of the acid and I'll give you the weight." <<     endl;
    getline(cin, acidName);

    cout << endl << endl;

    if (acidName == "valine") {

        acidWeight = "117.1469"; //make this as string

    }

    else {

        cout << "This doesn't appear to be valid." << endl;

}

    answerString = "The weight of " + acidName + "is " + acidWeight + "per mole";

    return answerString;
```

}